# Looking for a Manga/manhwa/manhua where 2 people end up in a sci fi world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I only read 2 chapters earlier and completely forgot to bookmark it, but as in the title, they end up in a sci fi world, but they end up in different locations. The boy gets trained by a woman (can't remember what she looked like) or the MC for that matter.

Comment: Try to dredge more clues from your memory. What language is the manga in? Was it translated from another language? When did you read it, and was the manga new then, or old?

Comment: It was English translated, but the Original was either Korean or Chinese (beacause it was full colored, something japanese manga rarely are). Trying to remember more, but it was over a year ago I read 2 chapters, so not mutch to dredge from sadly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Man, you didn't give us much to go on. It would help if you could squeeze out more details.

However, the closest thing I can think of to what little you've got is [Girl and Science:](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=153315)
[image: This is the cover.]

It's not really a sci fi setting. it's more like a sci fantasy setting. Here's the description on Mangaupdates:

"They were childhood friends, and she had always been more powerful than him. But when they accidentally travelled (summoned?) to another world, it was finally time for him to become the knight in shining armor! He had to find her first though, since they were separated... Come and witness his fight to be better in a crazy world where monsters roamed and technology was so advanced your amputated limbs be restored to perfection..."

Comment: Yes, that was it, the fact that you managed to find it with my extremely limited description was amazing. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.